# How do I serialize pouchdb changes processing?

Tags: pouchdb

It appears that before I complete processing a particular changed document, my function is being called with another changed document.

How can I make sure this is done in order?

Comment: Can you include the code you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this was to set up a queue data structure.

The change handler simply creates a task object containing 
details of the change and the appropriate processor function, and then pushes it onto the tail of the queue. The processor functions always end execution by checking the head of the queue for yet another queued task object.

Likewise, the change handler checks the head of the queue for a task object, and passes control to its processor function.

Consequently, all changes are processed in order and all changes are processed until the queue is empty.

All the functions are `async` and always called with `await`.

Comment: Nice! I can even resort the queue based on the timestamp inside if required. Like it!!

Comment: The function that pushes to the queue can be sync, no?

Comment: @sureshvv - Yes, you're right.  No need for `async` there.